# Almacenamiento de archivos en File Server

Tags: archivo, server

Normalmente se liga a que donde se tiene el File Server es en donde se almacenan todos los archivos, quiero saber si es posible por ejemplo montar un File Server en Windows pero que el almacenamiento de archivos se haga en un equipo que cuenta con alguna distribución de Linux, Ubuntu por ejemplo, he revisado el sistema de archivos de ambos sistemas operativos y he encontrado que el que es compatible con ambos es NTFS debido a que permite tanto la lectura y escritura en ellos, entonces pensaba en tener algún dispositivo de almacenamiento con un formato de NTFS y desde el servidor de Windows colocar la ruta a este, pero reitero quiero saber si es posible de realizar, de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Intenta instalando en Ubuntu un servidor SAMBA, recuerda que la partición donde almacenas la información debe estar en NTFS por los temas de lectura y escritura.

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#1-overview